# how to call Acceleo Generator (file.mtl) From Java Class without getting a java.io.IOException: 'generate.emtl' not found

Tags: java, eclipse, acceleo

I have created a Java Project using Eclipse. Inside it I have create a package (named generators) and I have moved inside it my generate.mtl file and Generate.java class.
After it I've created a java class and i try to call the method doGenerate() of a "Generate" object.

Doing it on the console appare this message:

java.io.IOException: 'generate.emtl' not found
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.service.AbstractAcceleoGenerator.initialize(AbstractAcceleoGenerator.java:307)
    at generatore.Generate.(Generate.java:90)
    at tests.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:49)

Why?
What I have to do?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The 'generate.emtl' file Acceleo is searching for is the compiled version of your 'generate.mtl' file (kind of what a '.class' is to a '.java'). When in Eclipse, this file is compiled automatically provided that you're using an "Acceleo Project" and not a regular Java project.

However, you have to either [manually compile it](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Acceleo/FAQ#How_can_I_compile_my_mtl_files_in_a_standalone_environment.3F) or copy it beside your "mtl" file when in standalone.